# How to add -Xlint:unchecked to my Android Gradle based project?

Tags: android, gradle, javac, lint

I tried to add the following to the root `build.gradle` file:

```
subprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(Compile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Libraries:ActionBarSherlock:compileRelease'.
> invalid flag: -Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is everything ok with only one parameter such as options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"  ??

Comment: Yes, it works. I've changed to `"-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"` and it worked for both :) If you want to create an answer with this, I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral maybe you should just answer it yourself formally and refer this shakalaca's comment.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

This is what worked for me:
(in your project's build.gradle)

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do it for only the main module, excluding the dependencies?

Comment: @aleb, I assume you mean only apply the setting to the current build.gradle and not to all build.gradle's (i.e. allprojects).  In that case, don't wrap it in an `allprojects` closure.

Comment: Is this supposed to make a difference on Lint runs?  For some reason, my Lint is displaying the exact same warning message regardless of `-Xlint:unchecked` setting.

Comment: I think it is better to add it to "build-extras.gradle" instead of "build.gradle".

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me although I am not sure where this answer came from. It seems ridiculous to me that by default the linter will raise an error with no information about the problem until you add these options.

Comment: for those who want to add parameters tag you need to add             options.compilerArgs << "-parameters"

Comment: uggggh, why can't these be added to a single invocation at the command prompt? Gradle has been a step back from maven.

Comment: Run `./gradlew lint` instead of `./gradlew lint -Xlint:Xlint:unchecked` or similar.

Answer (score 62):

> **Disclaimer:** Even though this answer has more than 10 upvotes, it does not address the problem in the context of an **Android** project. However, Google finds this question in the context of non-Android projects. Thus, I keep this answer for those folks.

According to [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html), the following seems to be solution:

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

If you want it to have for the test cases, use `compileTestJava`

```
compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

Comment: Does this go in the top-level build.gradle, or the module?

Comment: In the build.gradle file of the module.

Comment: Can you expand the context of that first snippet? Where in the `gradle.build` does it go?

Comment: This solution works for modules that are applying the `java` plugin in their `build.gradle` file but not for modules that are applying the `com.android.application` or `com.android.library` plugin.

Comment: @downvoters: Please comment why you downvote and please explain the  solution you found.

Comment: @koppor: see previous comment. Doesn't work for android developers. Which is a problem for a thread entitled "... Android gradle based project".

Answer (score 13):

For everyone using `gradle.kts` use the following to match up with the simple `build.gradle` file

**build.gradle.kts**

```
afterEvaluate {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile::class) {
            options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:unchecked")
            options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
        }
    }
```

**build.gradle**

```
 gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may also be able to write this as `tasks.withType<JavaCompile>` for 7 less characters.

Answer (score 8):

Put this in your **build.gradle** file (root directory):

```
allprojects { // Projects
   gradle.projectsEvaluated {
      tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
         options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
         options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a different compilation argument to set. The following works for me.

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"
        options.bootClasspath = "$System.env.JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar"
    }
}
```

You have to set the boot classpath for JDK 1.8 and above for things like Unsafe and sun.swing.* classes. Fix the source code especially for the latter, because Jigsaw Java 9, the up and coming modularity implementation for the JRE, will finally make these methods inaccessible(!). Consider yourself warned.

Answer (score 3):

For deprecation, you can now use this in gradle kotlin script, which is better than modifying `compilerArgs` because it's type-safe:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.isDeprecation = true
}
```

In higher version of Gradle I'd recommend using the new API:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
    options.isDeprecation = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the problem was about using the Gradle `subprojects` configuration parameter, but the syntax you used:

```
options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation"
```

This worked for me:

```
subprojects {
  gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
      options.compilerArgs += [
        '-Xlint:unchecked', // Shows information about unchecked or unsafe operations.
        '-Xlint:deprecation', // Shows information about deprecated members.
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
subprojects {
  gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
      options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want to add one option (you would normally add more), inside the task `JavaCompile` you just need to add:

```
options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
```

You can find more information about Lint [**here**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) and [**here**](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/lint).