# Compiler options missing in Android Studio >= 0.8.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotation-processing

Recently I upgraded my `Android Studio` to `0.8.2`. Now, my android-annotations based project fails to build. It seems like annotation processing is disabled somehow. It seems the project compiler settings have been changed, the option to turn annotation processing on/off is nowhere to be found...

[image: Compiler settings in 0.8.2]

I can't expand the 'Compiler' option as I could before:

[image: Expected compiler settings]

Where have they put these options?

Comment: Ok, this is just weird. I restarted Android Studio, reopened my project and now I have two 'Compiler' options, both options as shown in the screens above...

Comment: So only restart has solved your problem or maybe some additional acitons? Even after restart I still have this issue like (Compiler(Gradle-based Android Projects)) etc. and only one tab.

Answer (score 11):

This is a little late, but for me, it's under

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler

This compiler has dropdown options, including Annotation Processors.

Comment: There is no `Default Settings` under Other Settings in A.S. anymore.

Comment: It's moved to File -> New Projects Setup

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio 3.1.2 this setting is under:

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Additional command line parameters

[image]

---

**Update**

For more recent versions of Android Studio [tested on Android Studio 3.5 but probably starting from 3.4 according to Joel's comment] this setting is under:

File -> Other Settings -> Settings for New Projects... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Additional command line parameters

---

For existing projects it seems to me that the only option is to implement the solution described in these two answers [A1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183825/4092588) and [A2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28270322/4092588), modifying the `build.gradle` file wrapping around `allprojects` or not based on your needs:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

More details about Gradle's Multi-Project Builds can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) on their official website

Comment: With Open Studio 3.4.2 under Linux, I can't find the Java compiler options in any of these places. I would like to add the -Xlint:deprecation option to find out which API is obsolete when compiling code for bluetooth. The Compiler options I found in the "Build, execution, deployment" settings obviously only apply to Gradle. Does anybody know where to set the Java compiler options now?

Comment: @JoëlV. I just updated this answer, check now if it works for you [tested on the last Android Studio 3.5 for Windows but theoretically should be identical on Linux]

Comment: update is about "new projects", what about the current project

Comment: @meghraj27 I just updated the answer again, let me know if it solves your issue or not

Answer (score 0):

This option now is moved to:

> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle-Android
> Compiler -> Command-line Options:

[image: Screen of settings]