# Gradle Script message "Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details"

Tags: gradle, android-manifest

```
Note: --:-----\.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recompile with -Xlint in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740812/recompile-with-xlint-in-android-studio)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689365/how-to-add-xlintunchecked-to-my-android-gradle-based-project/34452265 This worked for me.
(upvoted with 246 votes)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to go **Gradle Scripts** the click on **build.gradle**
after **buildscript** you need to add

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

For example :

```
  buildscript {

     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }
  }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
       tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
       options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
     }
 }

   allprojects {
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```