# how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I was trying to run my Flutter app and this shows up:

```
    Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\IMBA\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_card_flutter-master\.dart_tool\flutter_build\410385fb4867e1d74565d68665ecb577\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\IMBA\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_card_flutter-master\.dart_tool\flutter_build\410385fb4867e1d74565d68665ecb577\kernel_snapshot.d
...
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:567:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:760:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:536:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:40:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:178:27)
#6      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\IMBA\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\IMBA\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And something else showed up after I used the `--scan` flag in the problem section.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:94)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:248)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I took all the material of this Flutter app from the appbrewery Flutter course. This happens when I was trying to make the MIcard project. Any thoughts to solving this problem?

Comment: U might need to consider downgrading check this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912637/how-can-i-fix-this-error-struct-utf8-is-empty-support-for-empty-structs-is-d)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go to `pubspec.yaml` file, try doing `Packages get | Pub get`, and then build the project again.

Answer (score 86):

Something that work for me is: Delete your `pubspec.lock`, and press 'Pub Get' in your `pubspec.yaml`, it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again and should fix the problem.

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same error and further, I tried:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
   in the terminal, and the issue solved!

Comment: Thanks, flutter clean was what I was missing

Answer (score 9):

I also tried this, thanks to [iapicca](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49507#issuecomment-578646648)

**run** in your terminal

`flutter channel stable`

`flutter upgrade --force`

`flutter pub cache repair`

next,

`cd <YOUR APP FOLDER>`

`flutter clean`

Comment: The `flutter pub cache repair` worked for me like a charm!!

Comment: after running `flutter pub cache repair` it shows me an error 1 package inactive... 
to resolve that I run `flutter pub global activate devtools` and again run `flutter pub cache repair` it worked like a charm.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked on my project thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just faced this issue, I solved it by removing an unused import

```
import 'dart:js';
```

the issue started when I added it by mistake, took a while to realize it was the issue

Comment: It was not the same package, but removing some unused imports resolve this issue for me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

This should work!!!

`flutter clean`,

---

`flutter pub get`,

---

`flutter build appbundle --release --no-tree-shake-icons`

Comment: What is the use of --no-tree-shake-icons here? What does it do?

Comment: @rehman_00001 it is use to shake out unused icons from awesome, material icon and any other package.

Answer (score 5):

## Deleting `pubspeck.lock` and `pub get`, didn't solve my problem.

---

**in my case its caused by  `import 'dart:html';`.**

> VSCode sometimes imports these libs automatically instead of what we
> want is `import 'dart:io'`;

Look for in your file which has `import 'dart:html';` and **delete** it. then you can run the app again.

Answer (score 4):

Optimizing imports (Ctrl + Alt + O) in Android Studio solved the issue for me.
[image: Studio Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Just in case, do this:

**IntelliJ/Android Studio:** "Edit Configurations" (in your run configurations) → "Additional run args".

**VS Code:** search for "Flutter run additional args" in your user settings.

Then, add:

```
--no-sound-null-safety
```

This fixed the problem for me.
What this basically does is that, if you use an import that doesn't support null safety, Flutter ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when indentation is not proper in pubspec.yaml file. Make sure font and other dependencies are having right indentation.

Answer (score 3):

this solution work for me :

1 - delete `pubspeck.lock`

2 - run `flutter clean`

3 - run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't build for iOS, so I deleted `flutter/bin/cache/artifacts`. iOS works well then building Android had the same error. I tried `flutter upgrade` and that solved the problem.

Comment: I did the same artifcat removal by following a youtube tutorial. Upgrading flutter solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Removing .gradle folder helped**

Gradle is located at

```
On Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.gradle

On Mac / UNIX: ~/.gradle
```

1. Close android studio.
2. Remove whole .gradle folder.
3. Open Android studio and build.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Deleted `build` and `android/app/build`.

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen for many reasons, and there are multiple solutions to solve this issue.

**Solution 1:**

Run following commands

```
flutter clean
```

"invalidate cache and restart" by navigating file>invalidate Caches

```
flutter pub get
```

Hit flutter run, hope this would work.

**Solution 2:**

Hit

```
flutter clean
```

Delete following files form your root-project directory

```
.dart_tool
.idea
build
pubspec.lock
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
```

"invalidate cache and restart" by navigating file>invalidate Caches

Open android folder into Android Studio, it would take some time and download all the packages

Open flutter project again, android studio do some indexing. then hit

```
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Enjoy! this solution should work

**Solution 3:**

Simply hit `flutter run`
it gives you list of errors (red & blue color) at above " Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'"

Read each error carefully, there would be a directory path from which you can get the package name of BAD EGG

Upgrade that imposter (Package) manually, And hit `flutter run` again

Repeat this process for each error, Once you solve the dependency issues among packages, that resolve your problem.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the `pubspec.yaml` file  and Download packages

OR

1. Go to Terminal `flutter pub get`
2. Upgrade Flutter `flutter upgrade --force`
3. Run Flutter App  `Press F5` or `flutter run`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might work for you

```
flutter clean,

flutter pub get,

flutter build apk --release --no-tree-shake-icons
```

If you have flavours then add flavour with the build command.
And update the minimumsdk to a higher version compatible with java version.

Comment: Also edit and add code part under the code braces in the editor!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by reading a different topic here: [Recompile with Xlint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740812/recompile-with-xlint-in-android-studio)

First, find your build.gradle file from the Android folder (Android/app/build.gradle)

Then paste the following code inside the android brackets `{}`:

```
allprojects {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}}
```

I have pasted it at the bottom before the end bracket and it worked for me.

After this, just restart your app and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution update flutter sdk.

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete **pubspec.lock** file and then **flutter clean** and **flutter pub get** .
This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

the packages that you added  are not updated . sometimes it is old version . so update  the pckages that mentioned under the dependencies in your  pubspec file    .

Answer (score 0):

I did fix the issue by removing an unused import:

```
import 'dart:developer';
```

So I will highly recommand you to remove all unused imports before trying any of the other solutions

Answer (score 0):

please check your asset rooting in pubspec.yaml

assets:
- assets/images/logo.svg

then thats clear

try to

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Flutter Upgrade" command to resolve this issue.

if you are using android studio, go to the menu options and select Tools-->Flutter-->Flutter Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me after reinstalling my machine and flutter setup.

In the end it was solved by removing the `dart.flutterSdkPath` from my VSCode `settings.json`.

Seems like it was some conflict with `fvm` and `homebrew`.