# flutter and firebase error invalid dep file kernel snapshot.d

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am working on some project and testing my app, everything is fine but suddenly firebase error occurs even i did not made any code mistake or any thing else :( . please some one take a minute to guide me and resolve my problem.

```
> ../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:34:18: Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
  final _xhrs = <HttpRequest>{};
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:306:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:340:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:345:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((e) => _idTokenChangedController.addError(e));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:164:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((update) => jsify(transactionUpdate(dartify(update))));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:166:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var onCompleteWrap = allowInterop(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:301:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var callbackWrap = allowInterop((database_interop.DataSnapshotJsImpl data,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:325:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    jsObject.once(eventType, allowInterop(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:402:22: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DataSnapshot'.
 - 'DataSnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var actionWrap = allowInterop((d) => action(DataSnapshot.getInstance(d)));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:72:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:75:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:87:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:97:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((_) => null);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:98:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart:317:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((storage_interop.UploadTaskSnapshotJsImpl data) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart:321:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart:322:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var onCompletion = allowInterop(() => _changeController.close());
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:194:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (js.hasProperty(error, 'message')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:195:19: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    var message = js.getProperty(error, 'message');
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:29:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'firestore') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:30:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'id') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:31:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'parent')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:37:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'latitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:38:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'longitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:44:15: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  var proto = util.getProperty(jsObject, '__proto__');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:46:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'toDate') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:47:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toMillis')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:52:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'isEqual') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:53:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toBase64')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:67:24: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    map[key] = dartify(util.getProperty(jsObject, key));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:91:17: Error: Method not found: 'newObject'.
    var jsMap = util.newObject();
                ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:93:7: Error: Method not found: 'setProperty'.
      util.setProperty(jsMap, key, jsify(value));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:116:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:124:5: Error: Method not found: 'callMethod'.
    util.callMethod(jsObject, method, args);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:139:19: Error: Method not found: 'promiseToFuture'.
    value = await util.promiseToFuture(thenable);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:141:9: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
    if (util.hasProperty(e, 'code')) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:152:27: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
  return PromiseJsImpl<S>(allowInterop((
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:165:5: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    allowInterop(c.completeError);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:173:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get code => util.getProperty(_source, 'code');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:176:25: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get message => util.getProperty(_source, 'message');
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:179:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get name => util.getProperty(_source, 'name');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:182:32: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  Object get serverResponse => util.getProperty(_source, 'serverResponse');
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:185:23: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get stack => util.getProperty(_source, 'stack');
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:105:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Firestore'.
 - 'Firestore' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var updateFunctionWrap = allowInterop((transaction) =>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:306:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((firestore_interop.DocumentSnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:445:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firestore_interop.QuerySnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:449:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:775:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((s) => callback(DocumentSnapshot.getInstance(s)));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/interop/js_interop.dart:17:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'toDateString')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:34: Error: 'Blob' isn't a type.
      var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
                                 ^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:46:15: Error: The method 'HttpRequest' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'HttpRequest'.
    var xhr = HttpRequest();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:42: Error: The method 'Blob' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Blob'.
      var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
                                         ^^^^
../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:59:20: Error: The method 'FileReader' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../../Flutter-SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FileReader'.
      var reader = FileReader();
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:853:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:574:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:182:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:9:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/Saif/Desktop/Flutter-SDK/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/Saif/Desktop/Flutter-SDK/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

this is the log output and after reviewing the logs i just remove firebase-7.3.0 too and its not works, runs flutter clean, change flutter channel from beta to stable but not works.

Comment: Could you try the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930399/11928130)? The issue seems to be similar to yours.

Comment: nopes... already tried but didn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after all i just got the issue, this appears due to

> firebase-7.3.0

and i removed it but didn't success, so again i checked all files and found one import for this dependency  it was not showing any error for import, the libraries just cached and appearing in my one file so i removed the import and run again it works