# flutter for windows setup

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, installation

So i started setting up flutter for windows. The process I follow

- DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL GIT
- DOWNLOAD FLUTTER
- ADDED PATH IN USERS AND ACCOUNTS OF FLUTTER BIN
- CHECK NORMAL CMD BY TYPING FLUTTER
- DOWNLOADED AND INSTALLED ANDROID STUDIO
- ADD FLUTTER AND DART PLUGIN IN IT
- SETUP THE EMULATOR
  then when I run main.dart instead of showing on emulator it shows me this error

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 29 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)".
F/crash_dump32(12343): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 12341)
F/crash_dump32(12699): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 12697)
F/crash_dump32(12726): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 12724)
F/crash_dump32(13296): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 13294)
"Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29
"Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" finished.
F/crash_dump32(14457): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 14455)
**ERROR STARTS FROM HERE**
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/thread_pool.cc: 299: error: Could not start worker thread: result = 22.
version=2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "windows_x64"
pid=16644, thread=16924, isolate_group=(nil)(0000000000000000), isolate=(nil)(0000000000000000)
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=7ff744a7f240

pc 0x00007ff744c100ec fp 0x000000457d2ff340 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17m 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Am i missing something how to solve this?
i would be thankful if you could help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter need to download the Gradle, try to create the project with Android Studio.