# How do I fix this? @@@

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 900
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: try doing `Flutter clean` or in pubspec.yaml-->pub get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)

Answer (score 0):

1. First run flutter doctor
2. Run flutter clean (Which will delete your build and give you a "clean state"
3. Then run flutter pub get (This way you get all the dependencies you need.
4. If you use flutter pub upgrade you might run into some issues if the latest versions of the packages are not compatible, so be careful!

That been said, you might have upgraded a package that is giving you issues.