# How can I fix this error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated... Use Opaque instead

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently started getting this error when I run my app. It doesn't seem to affect everything, but it is very noisy and annoying in the logs. I didn't change anything or add anything to my app that would cause something like this, the only thing I did recently was upgrade to the latest version of Flutter (I upgrade frequently, so it was only a few days since my last update).

```
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Info: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Info: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Info: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Info: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Info: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Info: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Info: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Info: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Info: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Info: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Info: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
```

The last error in the list looks slightly different:

```
../../../../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Info: Support for using non-constant type arguments 'T' in this FFI API is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Rewrite the code to ensure that type arguments are compile time constants referring to a valid native type.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I tried `flutter clean` but that didn't fix it.

Here's my `flutter doctor` output:

```
Flutter 1.26.0-13.0.pre.190 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7db172b24d (50 minutes ago) • 2021-01-26 17:18:40 -0800
Engine • revision b11bef83a5
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-263.0.dev)

Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-13.0.pre.190, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: try shifting to flutter stable channel

Comment: @SohelMahmud I tried flutter clean, I even mentioned it in my post ;)

Comment: I have the same issue. I think it would be changed in a couple of days

Comment: Same problem since upgrade Flutter 3 days ago.
I was on master channel. Change for stable channel fixed this problem.

Comment: This is harmless to your app, but we're working on fixing it upstream: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75113

Comment: Same error on windows 10 on Flutter 1.27.0-1.0.pre • channel dev when trying to run the app on mobile.

Answer (score 18):

Apparently this flutter SDK version has an errors, the previous version working well, you can solve this problems using this command in flutter console:

```
flutter downgrade
```

Comment: it worked, i bored all  flutter upgrades,

Comment: Same here, when I see "Flutter upgrade available" I just thinking "JESUS SAVE ME"...

Comment: Excited for Flutter Updates but sometime not to update is better for non-stable version developers.

Comment: First I upgrade the Flutter version. Then I get stuck on flutter_svg nullOk error. Then after digging to solutions, I come back to this comment. It's a loop.

Comment: @zackygaurav, try this (this is a temporary solution until null safety is supported in all packages):

```
dependency_overrides:
  xml: 4.5.1
  flutter_svg: 0.20.0-nullsafety.3
```

Explanation: You'll need a newer flutter_svg with null safety to make newer flutter sdk happy. But then you'll have `xml` package issues. This also solves those.

Answer (score 17):

I faced the same issue on dev channel. I solved the issue without downgrade. just add this dependency:

```
ffi: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: it helped & saved us a lot of debugging time! many thnx!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time, this should be the accepted answer, why to downgrade the version

Answer (score 6):

This is temporary for users on the `master` channel. FFI will soon no allow empty `Struct` objects, and instead classes like `Utf8` should now extend from `Opaque`. We're in an interim phase where the SDK has been upgraded but the `package:ffi` package hasn't been updated yet, hence the messages if you're running on the latest `master` build. The messages should be non-fatal.

Comment: how long is temporary? Its been a month

Comment: Thanks, Tim for the information, how long is temporary? Its been 6 months.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue , it's all with Flutter last version
Just downgrade and make sure you are on the Stable channel version not beta

```
flutter channel stable
```