# I have purchased source code for a dating app (in Flutter), and when I run the app in VS Code it shows this error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am new to flutter I have purchased source code for a dating app, written in Flutter, and when I run the app in VS Code it shows following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\temp\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line:
>   904
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\temp\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 2s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       131.4s (!)
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 PS
> C:\Users\manu\Downloads\codecanyon-26539930-matchindica-a-complete-flutter-based-dating-app\matchindicaCodecanyon7\matchindicaCodecanyon-SourceCode\matchindica>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Go to your pubspec.yaml file and click on get packages. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930399/14807758 answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)