# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' - flutter.gradle line: 1035

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart-pub, flutter2.0

I don't know what the problem with my Gradle.
I tried everything.

flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
delete .gradle
delete pubspec.lock

everything, but nothing.

I do not understand what could be. If anyone has an answer or can help me I would appreciate it

IDE: AndroidStudio

### **flutter run --verbose**

```
Persisting file store
[ ] [ +18 ms] Done persisting file store
[ ] [ +1 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
[ ] #0 KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/common.dart:291:7)
[ ]
[ ] #1 _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:828:9)
[ ]
[ ] #2 Future.wait. (dart:async/future.dart)
[ ]
[ ] #3 _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:766:32)
[ ]
[ ] #4 FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:595:16)
[ ]
[ ] #5 AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:318:32)
[ ]
[ ] #6 FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
[ ]
[ ] #7 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[ ]
[ ] #8 CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
[ ]
[ ] #9 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
[ ]
[ ] #10 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[ ]
[ ] #11 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
[ ]
[ ] #12 run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
[ ]
[ ] #13 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[ ]
[ ] #14 main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[ ]
[ ] [ +3 ms]
[ ] #0 throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
[ ] #1 AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:335:7)
[ ]
[ ] #2 FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
[ ]
[ ] #3 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[ ]
[ ] #4 CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
[ ]
[ ] #5 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
[ ]
[ ] #6 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[ ]
[ ] #7 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
[ ]
[ ] #8 run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
[ ]
[ ] #9 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[ ]
[ ] #10 main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[ ]
[ ] [ +8 ms] "flutter assemble" took 14.376ms.
[ +76 ms] [ +118 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 117ms
[ ] [ +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[ ] [ ] Shutdown hooks complete
[ ] [ ] exiting with code 1
[ +69 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[ ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[ ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[ ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[ ] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[ ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ ] * Where:
[ ] Script 'C:\Users\jeron\Downloads\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
[ ] * What went wrong:
[ ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[ ] > Process 'command 'C:\Users\jeron\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[ ] * Try:
[ ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[ ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[ ] BUILD FAILED in 17s
[ +335 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 18,4s)
[ +2 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[ +1 ms] "flutter run" took 19.233ms.
[ +2 ms]
#0 throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1 RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:663:9)

#2 FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)

#3 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)

#4 CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)

#5 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)

#6 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)

#7 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)

#8 run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)

#9 AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)

#10 main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[ +114 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 113ms
[ +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[ ] Shutdown hooks complete
[ ] exiting with code 1
```

---

### **flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18363.1500], locale es-AR)
• Flutter version 2.2.1 at C:\Users\jeron\Downloads\flutter
• Framework revision 02c026b (6 days ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
• Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
• Dart version 2.13.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\jeron\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\jeron\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: F:\Android\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.1)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.7.30406.217
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at F:\Android
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] Connected device (4 available)
• sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18363.1500]
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
• Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.46

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

### **My pubspec.yaml**

```
name: untitled
description: A new Flutter project.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  rxdart: ^0.26.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
  sticky_headers: ^0.2.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  image: ^3.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  permission_handler: ^6.1.3
  image_cropper: ^1.4.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  scoped_model: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  camera: ^0.8.1
  share: ^2.0.1
  flip_card: ^0.5.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.6
  flutter_masked_text2: ^0.9.1
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^19.1.58-beta
  flutter_swiper_null_safety: ^1.0.1
  flutter_sms: ^2.3.1
  local_auth: ^1.1.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.3
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4
  barcode_scan2: ^4.1.3
  contacts_service: ^0.6.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.21.0-nullsafety.0
  qr_mobile_vision: ^3.0.0
  animate_do: ^2.0.0
  flutter_exif_rotation: ^0.4.1
  app_settings: ^4.1.0
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  file_picker: ^3.0.1
  dashed_circle: ^0.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.4
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.1
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.6
  facebook_app_events: ^0.12.0

  screenshot: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.1
  flutter_html:  ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  collection: ^1.15.0-nullsafety.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.0.4
  json_serializable: ^4.1.3

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

---

### **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

---

### **app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    throw new GradleException("versionCode not found. Define flutter.versionCode in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    throw new GradleException("versionName not found. Define flutter.versionName in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.untitled"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

### **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: try disable sound null safety as mentioning on https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Comment: @jeronimo Did you find any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using flutter latest version.
The application runs with these versions:

```
dart: ">=2.4.0 <3.0.0"
flutter: ">=1.12.13+hotfix.4 <2.0.0"
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your packages which are used in your project to last version . I tried that and i get build.