# Error in loading YOLOv4 TFlite model in Flutter

Tags: c, flutter, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

I have loaded my custom YOLOv4 TFlite model on Flutter based on this [repo](https://github.com/TexMexMax/object_detection_flutter) by TexMexMax. I already followed all the instructions in the README.md but still got these errors:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/delegates/gpu_delegate.dart:58:10: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2'.
 - 'TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2' is from 'package:tflite_flutter/src/bindings/types.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        .addressOf);
         ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-0.5.0/lib/src/bindings/types.dart:6:7: Error: Struct 'TfLiteInterpreter' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class TfLiteInterpreter extends Struct {}
      ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
```

There are list of errors similar to the above but with different functions(?). Then the errors ended with below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I also tried some of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug) but still **no luck**. Apparently, according to [this author](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/issues/225#issuecomment-692474301), the TFLite plugins in Flutter doesn't support YOLOv4 yet hence I followed the repo by TexMaxMex since they had modified something so that Flutter could support the YOLOv4 model but then I encountered those errors.

Hope someone could enlighten me why is this happening and what should I do to assist the problems. Thank you in advance!