# GetX Flutter v4.6.1 some issues

Tags: flutter, dart, get, package, pubspec

In my project I used [GetX v4.6.1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi0pvzQnJD1AhXqT2wGHSJTCVEQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpub.dev%2Fpackages%2Fget&usg=AOvVaw16lu4j8eqYtpFvyp8t3ljU). When it Build on debug mode, I faced this bugs

```
/C:/Users/ALIF/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:275:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
                useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,         
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:217:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp.router({                                            
/C:/Users/ALIF/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:322:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.                                                                                                  useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:166:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ALIF/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_cupertino_app.dart:252:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.                                                                                                 useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart:189:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CupertinoApp.router({                                           
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                             
/C:/Users/ALIF/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_cupertino_app.dart:292:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
                useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,         
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart:145:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CupertinoApp({                                                  
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                    
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* Where:                                                                
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s                                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        87.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm also already followed this [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug) but still not resolve the issues. First time I faced this issues is when at MyApp widget (root) on my project would change from MaterialApp to be GetMaterialApp, only.

Comment: Please check it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562258/2637449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pubspec.yaml` use **get** package like below :

`get: 4.6.1`

# Don't use ^

Answer (score 1):

Please wrap with GetMaterialApp.

```
  return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: appTheme(),
      getPages: AppRoutes.getAppRoutes(),
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.INITIAL,
    );
```

Comment: Still receives similar errors

Comment: Can you share your startup code snapshot? It may a collection between GetMaterialApp and MaterialApp.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Hg5tJ0rZ in file main.dart

Answer (score 1):

for me solved !

if using like below :

```
  get: ^4.6.1
```

replace to :

```
  get: 4.5.1
```

and finally write in terminal :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Build task issues similar to what you've encountered could be usually solved by running `flutter clean` to clear the project's build cache and running `flutter pub get` to fetch the project's dependencies configured in the project's pubspec.yaml

If a package in your pub cache is broken, you can use `flutter pub cache repair` command to perform a clean reinstall of all hosted and git packages in the system cache.

Answer (score 0):

I hv same issue. I solved by reducing GetX version into :

```
#In pubspec.yaml use get package like below :

get: 4.5.1
```

This doesn't work for me:

```
#In pubspec.yaml use get package like below :

get: 4.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by reducing GetX version into : get: 4.2.4
flutter version 2.0.6
dart version 2.12

android/app/build.gradle
set like this;

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
................
}