# How to solve this issue Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have a already try multiple methods but failed,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\IMBA\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\IMBA\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

give me a prefect suggestion

Comment: Please follow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76853220/16194683 hope this solution work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the packages in your project. Check if there is any package that needs to be updated.

I've update the package flutter_settings_ui: ^2.0.1 to latest and it solved the issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete your pubspec.lock file
2. go to your pubspec.yaml file and click on pub get
   now automatically generate file and fix your your.

Answer (score 1):

You need this line:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show BuildContext, Key, MaterialApp, StatelessWidget, Widget, runApp;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.