# Awesome notification V0.7.1 fails to build

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

I'm having this problem, and ran out of options,
I tried all solutions mentioned in below link but with no success

[how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)

```
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/awesome_notifications-0.7.1/lib/src/utils/resource_image_provider.dart:41:26: Error: Type 'DecoderBufferCallback' not found.
      ResourceImage key, DecoderBufferCallback decode) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/awesome_notifications-0.7.1/lib/src/utils/resource_image_provider.dart:49:26: Error: Type 'DecoderBufferCallback' not found.
      ResourceImage key, DecoderBufferCallback decode) async {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/awesome_notifications-0.7.1/lib/src/utils/resource_image_provider.dart:22:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ResourceImage' is missing implementations for these members:
 - ImageProvider.load
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ResourceImage extends ImageProvider<ResourceImage> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:567:24: Context: 'ImageProvider.load' is defined here.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/awesome_notifications-0.7.1/lib/src/utils/resource_image_provider.dart:41:26: Error: 'DecoderBufferCallback' isn't a type.
      ResourceImage key, DecoderBufferCallback decode) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/awesome_notifications-0.7.1/lib/src/utils/resource_image_provider.dart:49:26: Error: 'DecoderBufferCallback' isn't a type.
      ResourceImage key, DecoderBufferCallback decode) async {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: facing the same problem,any luck fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Basically  the awesome notifications is trying to access "DecoderBufferCallback" variable from the flutter library but sadly in the flutter library they changed that variable name to "DecoderCallback"...

SO you need to actually edit the variable name in the library code of AwesomeNotifications from "DecoderBufferCallback" to "DecoderCallback".. This is their job but we are doing it for them

P.S.: I know the awesoome notifications version is older in this screenshot but i just wanted to show where to do the edit... so i opened up an older project

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue with [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) after i upgraded from flutter 3.10.0 (Master channel) to flutter 3.13.1.
Switching to the stable channel solved the issue for me.

1. Check wich channel you are using. Type on the terminal: `flutter channel`.
   Your current channel is mark with a star like you can see on the image
   [image]
2. If you are not on the stable channel, then switch to it with: `flutter channel stable`
3. Finish with: `flutter upgrade`