# Execution failed for task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

Hi i don`t know what to do with this problem every time when i want to run my project

this Error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Could not write file to C:\Users\elkha\OneDrive\Документы\crypto_list2\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv

Target debug_android_application failed: ShaderCompilerException: Shader compilation of "C:\Users\elkha\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\shaders\ink_sparkle.frag" to "C:\Users\elkha\OneDrive\Документы\crypto_list2\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag" failed with exit code 1.
impellerc stdout:

impellerc stderr:
Could not write file to C:\Users\elkha\OneDrive\Документы\crypto_list2\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\elkha\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\elkha\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.elcode.crypto_list2"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

My build.gradle2:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.overridePathCheck=true
```

I run it in Andtoid Studio but in VS it gives me this two error it says that i need to update my jdk in gradle from 1.8 to 11 i search solution for this problem but i don`t found anything , i try to channge it in android studio Project Settings but in gradle settings there is not Gradle project stettings to change jdk, i try to change from build.gradle but it is not work.In stackoverflow i found one solution it say that i need to change my gradle version to older but it not work too.I use emulator and when i run it on chrome it works.Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug. Please follow this link

Answer (score 3):

Faced same exact error `impellerc stdout:...` when building my sample flutter on my mac laptop.

I was able to resolve this error using the following steps below :

1. On your Mac, choose `Apple menu > System Settings`.
2. Scroll and click `Privacy & security`, then scroll down to `security` section.
3. Click the lock icon to unlock it,
   then enter an administrator name and password. Select the sources
   from which you’ll allow software to be installed: *There should be a
   button that says "Allow anyway" which when clicked will prompt for administrator name and password. If not make sure you've cancelled
   the error dialog.*

[image: impellerc]

Dev Environment:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Flutter       3.7.1
Gradle        7.6
Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
JVM:          17.0.6 (Homebrew 17.0.6+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.0 aarch64
```