# Not being able to run app after updating Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Edit**: Solved! Both flutter_math_fork and flutter_layout_grid were packages I didn't installed by myself, so I wasn't finding them in the pubspeck.yaml. However, it seems those were dependencies for flutter_html - that was the one causing the error. I had to take it out and find another package for managing html text, and now everything's fine

---

After updating quite some versions, to be up to date, I'm no longer being able to run my app - I get a Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception every time. I already checked all the dependencies in pubspec.yaml and I can't find anything outdated there. In fact, the two packages throwing the errors are from flutter itself.

This is the error:

```
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:186:20: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
 - 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
 - 'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onTapDown: onTapDown,
                   ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:190:24: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapUpDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpDetails)?'.
 - 'TapUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
 - 'TapDragUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onSingleTapUp: onSingleTapUp,
                       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:195:26: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
 - 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
 - 'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDoubleTapDown: onDoubleTapDown,
                         ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:196:31: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragStartDetails)?'.
 - 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'TapDragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDragSelectionStart: onDragSelectionStart,
                              ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:197:32: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'.
 - 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'DragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'TapDragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
                               ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:198:29: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'.
 - 'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
                            ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:82:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
      final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
                                                      ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:83:58: Error: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsPlacement'.
      if (targetParent is RenderLayoutGrid) targetParent.markNeedsPlacement();
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:84:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
      if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:132:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
      final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
                                                      ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:133:58: Error: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsPlacement'.
      if (targetParent is RenderLayoutGrid) targetParent.markNeedsPlacement();
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:134:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
 - 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
      if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\jjj\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already started a whole new project and copy/paste the lib. I also both repaired and deleted the pub cache. However, if I try to run a new vanilla project, the new Flutter counter app, I can build it without problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't... I already tried, but also, having had a fresh start, with a new altogether project, should also avoid any of those problems, I think...

Comment: Solved! Both flutter_math_fork and flutter_layout_grid were packages I didn't installed by myself, so I wasn't finding them in the pubspeck.yaml. However, it seems those were dependencies for flutter_html - that was the one causing the error. I had to take it out and find another package for managing html text, and now everything's fine.

Comment: please post an answer ... do not add `solved .....` to the question ... do not write an answer in a comment

Answer (score 0):

add flutter_layout_grid: ^2.0.5 to your packages