# Unable to run app on emulator and physical device

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm currently taking an Udemy (https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/)
course on Flutter and while on it, I've been able to do most of the setups.
My (Default) demo code could compile and display web apps [image: screenshot of demo page] but couldn't display on
my physical device and emulator in both VS code and Android Studio.

Whenever I compile it, it displays the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after some time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2902)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2811)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1927)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried installing JDK, and followed several steps provided here on Stackoverflow like
[how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug), I have also done some github suggestions like flutter --v, flutter clean, flutter run
but they didn't work for me.

Here is the main.dart code by the way:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter - The Complete Guide',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          //
          // TRY THIS: Invoke "debug painting" (choose the "Toggle Debug Paint"
          // action in the IDE, or press "p" in the console), to see the
          // wireframe for each widget.
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could provide a solution to this.

Comment: Did you run flutter doctor ? Is it showing any issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by wiping all the files inside my: `C:\Users\user\.gradle\wrapper\dists` directory.
When I ran it after that on VS Code, it installed a lot of tools and the problem was resolved.
[image: Image of app]

Comment: Please [embed images directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853) instead of including a link, especially if it's to an external site.

Comment: @jesse Okay, thanks for your corrections

Answer (score 0):

For Android device,

Foremost you should stop you'r emulator on pc. because you can not run flutter project multiple devices without give some specific settings. you'r main issue is as my knowledge you'r not stop you'r emulator.

If you want run multiple devices read [this](https://flutteragency.com/run-app-on-multiple-connected-devices-simultaneously/) article

1. First, you should enable [Developer option](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) in you'r physical device
2. Then connect you'r device into you'r computer, at that time you will see some popup on you'r physical device you should give access USB debugging with you'r computer.
3. Now you can run you'r app on you'r physical device.

Comment: This was part of what I did before posting here, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs because of gradle version that you have on your project and the gradle versions available on your pc are different or the version set on the project is unreachable anyway.

try downgrading your gradle version from `android>build.gradle: dependencies`

and try to have same versions of gradle with

```
android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=
```

Answer (score -1):

You can able to fix this issue by cleare your wipe data on you'r emulator

Goto you'r Android studio. Then chick device manager. Click more action. Now you can wife you'r data.

It will be fix you'r issue if you'r not yet fix it change you'r api level as 24  .[image: How to clear wipe data]

Comment: Both wiping the data and switching to API 24 didn't solve it

Comment: Did you debug  you'r project  without run without debugging. and found where return the exception. and provide it.

Comment: I did. Where do you find exception?

Comment: Check you'r debug console you can got it.

Comment: Debug console says exactly the error i shared up

Comment: Remove you'r  virtual device and reinstall again and try.

Comment: Did you run Flutter -doctor cammand

Comment: I did both steps. Didn't work

Comment: What is the return when you'r run the flutter -doctor

Comment: Too long so here's a link https://pastebin.com/FjzNw6q8