Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'
Recently i upgraded my flutter project to support flutter sdk version 3.22.x, i was using Android studio Hedgehog. It worked fine.
After project upgrade, i updated the android studio from Hedgehog to Koala, now i am not able to run the flutter project, getting this error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/username/development/flutter/bin/flutter''

I have different flavors in this application, other project that don't have flavors works fine.
I have tried:

Deleting pubspec.lock, clean, pub get and build again
Invalidate cache and restart
flutter pub cache repair
Also tried this option, but i don't find any dart related error in the code.


Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug

@SumitBanwakade I tried, but it didn't work, so for now i have rolled back to Android studio Hedgehog. Thanks. Will check it in the future.

Finally, I was able to fix the issue, with Android Studio Koala.
Here's the fix that worked for me, in case anyone is looking for the solution, can give this a try.
In gradle-wrapper.properties file, distribution url needs to be set as follows:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip

And in settings.gradle file, I updated AGP version and Kotlin version as follows:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}

