How do I fix the "Execution failed for task ':app '" error in Flutter?
I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to run my first app on an Android emulator. However, I keep running into an error during the build process. Here’s the error message I’m getting:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Here are the steps I followed:
Installed Flutter SDK and set up my environment.
Created a new Flutter project using flutter create my_app.
Ran flutter run to launch the app on the Android emulator.
But the build fails with the above error. I've tried searching for solutions but haven't found anything that works. Here is my flutter doctor -v output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on macOS 14.3 23D56 darwin-arm64, locale en-NL)
    • Flutter version 3.22.1 on channel stable at /Users/haseebmalik/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision a14f74ff3a (6 weeks ago), 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
    • Engine revision 55eae6864b
    • Dart version 3.4.1
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/haseebmalik/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile)     • emulator-5554         • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                 • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.3 23D56 darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad • darwin         • macOS 14.3 23D56 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • chrome                • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.127

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug
