# Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>
> Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I found many posts about this issue but none that says how to deal in android studio.
Where i can set this system property in this IDE, for the project only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recompile with -Xlint in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740812/recompile-with-xlint-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and found the answer elsewhere.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50675771/2771087) says that it can be configured in Android Studio's settings under Build Execution -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Additional command line parameters, but I couldn't find the Java Compiler section with 3.1.3 even though the answer was for 3.1.2.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28270322/2771087) explaining how to change the gradle files is what worked for me, reproduced below:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

Comment: unchecked option it is not required to solve the stated problem.  Anyway problem solved, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I was in divided on whether to adjust for you question or just reproduce verbatim. I went with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I add it to build.gradle(app) and it worked:

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       javaCompileOptions {
           ...
           gradle.projectsEvaluated {
                tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
                }
            }
```