# Output Warnings as Errors using the Gradle Java Plugin?

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

I want that the java gradle plugins outputs warnings as errors when I do `gradle build` or `gradle compileJava`.

I tried to insert the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            // Warnings as errors
            options.compilerArgs <<  '-Werror'
        }
    }
}
```

or this:

```
compileJava {
 options.compilerArgs << "-Werror"
}
```

But the result is the same. Compile works without reporting anything.

**How can I output warnings as error using the Gradle Java plugin?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689365/how-to-add-xlintunchecked-to-my-android-gradle-based-project

Comment: @tim_yates No this does not work for me.

Comment: @confile I have same problem , have you got any solutions?