# Xlint deprecation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello I'm facing this problem when im building my app I searched the internet and found no clue, android studio give me this warning my app run with no problem but if anyone can clarify what is this and how to solve it :

(ImageGallery.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.)

this is the ImageGallery.java

```
    package com.akofahi.tourjordan;


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview.MediaInfo;
    import com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview.ScrollGalleryView;
    import com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview.loader.DefaultImageLoader;
    import com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview.loader.MediaLoader;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ImageGallery extends FragmentActivity {
        private static final ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "",
                "",
                ""
        ));
        private static final String movieUrl = "";

    private ScrollGalleryView scrollGalleryView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub_about_readmore_image_gallary);

        List<MediaInfo> infos = new ArrayList<>(images.size());
        for (String url : images) infos.add(MediaInfo.mediaLoader(new PicassoImageLoader(url)));

        scrollGalleryView = (ScrollGalleryView) findViewById(R.id.imgGallery);
        scrollGalleryView
                .setThumbnailSize(100)
                .setZoom(true)
                .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
                .addMedia(MediaInfo.mediaLoader(new DefaultImageLoader(R.drawable.petra)))
                .addMedia(MediaInfo.mediaLoader(new DefaultImageLoader(toBitmap(R.drawable.ram))))
                .addMedia(MediaInfo.mediaLoader(new MediaLoader() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isImage() {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void loadMedia(Context context, ImageView imageView,
                                          MediaLoader.SuccessCallback callback) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(toBitmap(R.drawable.wadi));
                        callback.onSuccess();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void loadThumbnail(Context context, ImageView thumbnailView,
                                              MediaLoader.SuccessCallback callback) {
                        thumbnailView.setImageBitmap(toBitmap(R.drawable.wadi));
                        callback.onSuccess();
                    }
                }))
                .addMedia(infos);
    }

    private Bitmap toBitmap(int image) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(image)).getBitmap();
    }
}
```

and this is my gradle.build:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.akofahi.tourjordan"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
        implementation 'com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview:library:1.0.8'
        implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'





    }
```

Comment: The message ```ImageGallery.java: uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.``` means the following: 
You are using a deprecated API, and the compiler complains about this. Use the compiler option `-Xlint:deprecation` to get more details.

Comment: kindly can u tell me how to use it ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689365/how-to-add-xlintunchecked-to-my-android-gradle-based-project).