# How to run cordova build with -Xlint:deprecation

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

when building my plugin with

```
cordova build
```

Cordova reports that my plugin is using deprecation API and for more info I should

```
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

But how can I pass **-Xlint:deprecation** as parameter to cordova build?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an Android build related problem, you could try to disable Xlint:deprecation flag, as is said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7847605/4627980)

1. Go to the $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/ant/main_rules.xml file and copy
   the "compile" target.
2. Paste it into your build.xml file before the  task.
3. Then add the following element to the task: `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation"/>`
4. Likewise, you can add other compiler options, such as for unchecked operations: `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>`